# Is there anything like a "void lambda" in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, lambda, void

That is, a lambda that takes no input and returns nothing.

I was thinking of clever ways to mimic switch statements in Python. Here's what I attempted (to no avail):

```
statement = {
    "Bob": lambda: print "Looking good, Bob!",
    "Jane": lambda: print "Greetings, Jane!",
    "Derek": lambda: print "How goes it, Derek?"
}[person]()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python

Comment: All lambdas, like functions, return *something*; the default is `None`. Just ignore the return value. Your problem is with trying to use a statement where only expressions can be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The contents of a lambda function must be a single expression; no statements are allowed.  Moreover, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt) is a statement in Python 2.x.  This means that you cannot use it inside a lambda.

If you want to use the Python 3.x [`print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), you can import it from [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) like so:

```
# Add this line to the top of your script file
from __future__ import print_function
```

Now, `print` can be used inside lambdas because it is a function:

```
statement = {
    "Bob": lambda: print("Looking good, Bob!"),
    "Jane": lambda: print("Greetings, Jane!"),
    "Derek": lambda: print("How goes it, Derek?")
}[person]()
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but you may want to add commas there

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, you're probably better off doing:

```
print {
    "Bob": "Looking good, Bob!",
    "Jane": "Greetings, Jane!",
    "Derek": "How goes it, Derek?"
}[person]
```

or

```
statement = {
    "Bob": "Looking good, Bob!",
    "Jane": "Greetings, Jane!",
    "Derek": "How goes it, Derek?"
}[person]
print statement
```

For more complex `switch`-like applications, the `dict` could hold function references, of course.

I'm also fond of composing function names as strings:

```
class Greeter(object):
    ... 
    def _greet_Bob(self): ...
    def _greet_Jane(self): ...
    def _greet_Derek(self): ...

    def greet(self,person):
        getattr( self, "_greet_"+person )()
```